# modify string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to modify a string in JavaScript as required.suppose
 I have a string `4x` i need to insert * between 4 and x and
 get it as `4*x`
if it is `9x` i should get it as `9*x` etc
if it is `sin(4x)` i should get it as `sin(4*x)`
if it is `sin(x)` i should get it as `sin(x)`.
if it is `sin(4 x+5)` i should get it as `sin(4*x+5)`
how to do this in java script.
any help is appreciable.

Comment: If you're building a calculator, there are probably better ways to do this than trying to insert entered operands into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with capturing group

```js
document.write('4x , 5x , 5x+3 , sin(4 x+5) , sin(4x)'.replace(/(\d+)\s*([a-z])/ig,'$1*$2'));
```

Comment: it was really helpful.Thanks pranav